# Random freezes, pointer moves, no response to clicks

Tags: reboot, freeze, random, highlighting

Why is my laptop freezing?
Screen randomly freezes, I can move pointer but no response to clicking. Cannot alt-tab through windows.
This happens in firefox and chromium. Ran memtester, all ok. Set FF to erase data, memory when closing, cleared memory & data, increased files open (ulimit -u) to 4096 when I saw the error message: too many files open - still freezes. (It just now froze as I was typing this message!) It can freeze after one minute or 30 minutes. Must hold power button to force off. Same happens in Ubuntu and Mint. System Monitor shows that FF never uses more than 1.5% of cpu and there are no other processes using more cpu time. One clue is that shortly before it freezes moving the mouse will start highlighting every line it passes and will only un-highlight by pulling the cursor back, and cannot stop any further highlighting. Must force reboot to get back control.

Firefox 106.0.1
Chromium 106.0.5249.119

Laptop Make: Model > Framework: Laptop AB
OS: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64
DE: GNOME 42.3.1
Kernel: 6.0.2-76060002-generic
Shell: bash 5.1.16
WM: Mutter
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7 (8) @ 4.700GHz
CPU Usage: 11%
Disk (/): 15G / 220G (8%)
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
GPU Driver: i915
Memory: 3008MiB / 15785MiB (19%)
Resolution: 2256x1504

Comment: I can definitely say that it is not the mouse as I had supposed. The unique thing about this problem is that when the pointer is moved a highlighted box forms on the screen, using the pointer's starting spot as the focus of this box. Nothing I click will cause the box to disappear. Occasionally I can get to the terminal and force the laptop to reboot but that seems to happen more by chance than design.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have solved the problem, it's the mouse itself that is messing up. The mouse is 18 months old but I have been clicking on it every day. Now I have been using my laptop for 3 or four hours straight without a problem. For the first hour I turned off the mouse and it worked fine. I am now using another BT mouse and the laptop is still working. So, after different OSes, different browsers, the only thing in common to all sessions was me and the mouse. We cannot dismiss or bypass my erratic behavior, but switching mice was easy.

Answer (score 0):

**Not Solved.**
Still having the problem. Have re-installed ubuntu, erasing disk. Still have the problem, but I will post the problem in Ask Ubuntu.